# Trying to pass images to shell command using automator

Tags: automator, sips

I am creating this service for Finder that will receive image files and pass to a shell command.

The idea is this:

1. I select image files on finder.
2. I right click and choose the service I am creating
3. the service receives the files and passes to sips, so it will scale the images to a given size.

this is how I created it.

sips would run on terminal if I type

```
sips -z 750 1334 *.png   (or any other extension, including *.*)
```

I am hoping that $* would pass a list of arguments to sips, but this is not working.

How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a following solution that works for me:

```
for f in "$@"; do
  sips -z 750 1334 "$f"
done
```

Comment: nice one, glad you found a solution that works for you. For us who do not understand, what does it do ? (why $f) but you got a + anyway :)

Comment: good question, but it works! thanks anyway +1 to you too!

Comment: `$f` comes from the `f` in Line 1: `for f ...`; Line 1 pseudocode: `for {each file} in {input list of files}`

Comment: to resize by width only (maintaining aspect ratio), another option is to use `sips --resampleWidth 750 "$f"`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `$@`:

```
sips -z 750 1334 "$@"
```

Comment: not working. I have found an answer. See my answer.